# User rapidly uploading media causes failure in mongoengine

Tags: mongoengine

Say I have an object like this:

```
class Thing(Document):
    name = StringField()
    age = IntField(unique_with='name')
```

then users can upload 100 things a second, so maybe I have an endpoint with some logic like:

```
try:
    new_thing = Thing.objects.get(name=name,
                                  age=age)
except DoesNotExist:
    new_thing = Thing(name=name,
                      age=age).save()
```

but I'll get an error that looks like this sometimes:

`NotUniqueError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error collection: my-db.thing index: name_1_age_1 dup key: { : "thing1", : 100 })`

because I believe if a user sends two of these requests, they could be evaluated in this order:

```
req1 = "Thing1", 100
re12 = "Thing2", 100

req1 => doesn't exist, continue
req2 => doesn't exist, continue
req1 => creates object in database
req2 => tries to create object in database, violates NotUniqueError and raises "[500]"
```